# how to send a list in python requests GET

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to GET some data from the server. I'm doing a GET with the python requests library:

```
my_list = #a list ['x', 'y', 'z']
payload = {'id_list': my_list}
requests.get(url, params=payload)
```

my server accepts a url: `https://url.com/download?id_list`

but when I send this get request, I get an error:

> `<h1>400 Bad Request</h1> 
>   The server cannot understand the request due to malformed syntax.
>   <br /><br /> Got multiple values for a parameter:<br /> 
>   <pre>id_list</pre>`

I saw the log and the request looks like this:

`url/download?id_list=x&id_list=y&id_list=z`

how can I fix this?

Comment: Send it as json instead: `requests.get(url, json=payload)`

Comment: @BobDylan I'll try that :)

Comment: @BobDylan that didn't work. I got another error `can't find parameter id_list`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, there's actually nothing to fix, the issue being on the server side! The way `requests` handle list per default is the way it should be handled.

But the real question you should be asking is what does the server side's API expect?

And once you know that you can mimic it using `requests`.

For example, it's likely to be that the server is expecting a `json` string as argument of the `id_list` parameter. Then you could do:

```
payload = {'id_list': json.dumps(my_list)}
```

But it can be that the server side expects a comma separated list:

```
payload = {'id_list': ','.join(my_list)}
```

So it's up to you to read the documentation (or hack your way around) of the API you try to communicate with.

---

N.B.: as @bob_dylan suggests you can try with `requests.get(url, json=payload)` but afaict, json payloads are usually used in `POST` queries, rarely in `GET`s.

Comment: thanks for this, at least I can narrow it down to the server!

Comment: The issue could be on the server's framework, that compiles the `GET` parameters into a `dict`, and as it's doing it, instead of building a list when there's several identical keys, it might raise an exception when it adds a new `(key, value)` pair where there's already another value with that key in the `dict`. But that's just speculation.

Comment: The issue is when passing the value for 'params=' not 'payload='. These are different functions in Requests. I have the same issue passing a list using params=. Assigning a query string list to payload does not help.

Answer (score 5):

A good way to solve this problem is by using request.GET.getlist() on the server.

It allows you to use something like this:

```
import requests
requests.get(url, data={'id_list': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
```

And make it on the server:

```
request.GET.getlist('id_list')
```

Returning exactly what you want:

```
>>> ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

It will also return a list when you send only one item.