# Multiple values for a key in parameter for get request

Tags: python

I am facing an issue where i need to send multiple values to parameters in the get response.

For example

```
API is URL =https://localhost:9090?id=1&department=hr
```

Now in `id` I want to send `1,2,3,4` in a single request and I did like

```
PARAMS = {'id': [1,2,3,4],'department'='hr'}

r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
```

It is not still giving the desired response as it is showing value for only `id =4`. Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: You expect this result => `id=1,2,3,4`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to send a list in python requests GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851315/how-to-send-a-list-in-python-requests-get)

Answer (score 2):

When given a sequence, requests duplicates the key as you can see in the example from the official documentations.

```py
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': ['value2', 'value3']}

>>> r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
>>> print(r.url)
https://httpbin.org/get?key1=value1&key2=value2&key2=value3
```

note `key2=value2` and `key2=value3`, that's the standard encoding for multiple values (there are others e.g. comma or semicolon-separated values, or "magic" key names postfixed with `[]` as in PHP).

However depending on your server-side framework that may require using special APIs to get the values as lists, otherwise you might get just the first or just the last because the querystring is interpreted as a 1:1 dict (here you only get the last one).

So your solutions are:

1. fix the server side, use whatever the proper API is to get multiple values for a key
2. or define your own encoding for multi-valued query strings and use that explicitly when performing the request (and when parsing it on the server-side unless the framework has built-in support for that encoding)

Answer (score 0):

Normally strings are send back and forth. In this case you may try:

`PARAMS = {'id': '1,2,3,4','department' : 'hr'}`

At server side you need to decode ID be using id.split(','). Then you get the four independent values again.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a server-side issue. Check whether the server is parsing the `id` field as intended or not. It would be much better if you could post the server code where the `id` field is being parsed.